# Doxygen: using same list for multiple \xrefitem commands

Tags: doxygen

I've created 4 custom commands using xrefitem and aliases, each command being the first name of one of the 4 programmers working on our project.  My idea was to have a person use their own name as a command when they wanted to leave a comment or ask a question at a specific point in the code, and keep track of all of the comment references in a list under related pages, like the bug and todo lists.

I wanted to set it so that each command would generate its own unique heading based on the persons name, but would all be added to the same list.

```
john   =\xrefitem john \"John says\" \"Comments\"
bob    =\xrefitem bob \"Bob says\" \"Comments\"
dave   =\xrefitem dave \"Dave says\" \"Comments\"
george =\xrefitem george \"George says\" \"Comments\"
```

Using the above aliases, the output is exactly as I want it, but each command generates its own Comments resource file for each name, instead of just adding to an already existing one as I had hoped it would.

```
john   =\xrefitem comments \"John says\" \"Comments\"
bob    =\xrefitem comments \"Bob says\" \"Comments\"
dave   =\xrefitem comments \"Dave says\" \"Comments\"
george =\xrefitem comments \"George says\" \"Comments\"
```

Using a singular key for each, as above, gives me a singular resource file as I wanted, but only uses the heading of the first command called in the code (a call to any of the 4 names would produce "John says" for example).

Can I specify somewhere that if the list xrefitem is set to write to already exists, just add to it instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section heading and the list are both coupled to the same identifier, so what you want is not possible at the moment.

If you wish to make this an official feature request then please submit a bug report in doxygen's bug tracker with severity set to enhancement.